# Is there a way to SQL "set field if", when multiple fields being updated, without using dynamic generation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

Given a basic update like:

```
update [X]
set A = @a
  , B = @b
```

Is there a way, using a single UPDATE, to set A or B *individually*?

The following will also update both fields, although it might show the desired intent. Such is *logically* valid and SQL Server will happily perform the update regardless of if the same value is supplied.

```
update [X]
set A = CASE WHEN @a IS NOT NULL THEN @a ELSE A END -- could be "a more complex" rule
  , B = CASE WHEN @b IS NOT NULL THEN @a ELSE B END
```

I know this can be handled by multiple UPDATE statements or Dynamic SQL.

Is there another approach such that fields are *not* updated at all (logically or otherwise)?

An argument could be made that if *any* value was to be set, the entire row has been modified, and thus an appropriate WHERE would be semantically equivalent to the request.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually update fields *individually*.  An entire row is updated.  Actually, worse than that, the entire *data page* containing the row is updated.

For what you want, this is the typical solution:

```
update [X]
    set A = coalesce(@a, A),
        B = coalesce(@b, B)
    where @a is not null or @b is not null;
```